# Vuetify Validation checking doesn't work in Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I tried to translate Javascript to Typescript in components of Vuetify web site code.
In validation check, I made Typescript code and no type errors found. But, on the brower showed an error occurred and I can't see any components I made.
console has no error, too.
I heard someone Vuetify is not 100% followed Typescript, and I'm beginner Engineer.
But my first client needs nuxt.js flamework using Typescript.
Please someone advise that kinda problem.
I don't understand why displayed no error, but displayed an error occurred.

reference   [Validation with submit and clear in Vuetify website](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/)

my code below ↓ My development environment is nuxt.js and also useing vue.js and Vuetify.js.

```
<template>
  <v-row align="center">
    <v-form
     ref="validattion"
     v-model="valid"
     :lazy-validation="lazy">
     <v-text-field
      v-model="name"
      :counter="10"
      :rules="[nameRules.required,nameRules.name_length]"
      label="Name"
      required></v-text-field>

      <v-text-field
      v-model="email"
      :rules="[emailRules.required,emailRules.email_validation]"
      label="E-mail"
      required></v-text-field>

      <v-select
       v-model="select"
       :items="items"
       :rules="[v=>!!v||'Item is required']"
       label="Item"
       required></v-select>

      <v-checkbox
       v-model="checkbox"
       :rules="[v=>!!v||'you must agree to continue!!']"
       label="Do you agree?"
       required>
      </v-checkbox>

      <v-btn
       :disabled="!valid"
       color="success"
       class="mr-4"
       @click="validate">Validate</v-btn>

      <v-btn
       color="error"
       class="mr-4"
       @click="reset">Rest</v-btn>

      <v-btn
       color="warning"
       class="mr-4"
       @click="resetValidation">Rest Validation</v-btn>

     </v-form>  
  </v-row>  
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class validationNao extends Vue {
  valid:boolean = true;
  lazy:boolean = false;
  name:string='';

  nameRules={
     required:(v:string) => !!v || 'Name is required',
     name_length:(v:string) => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters',
  };

  email:string='';
  emailRules={
    required:(v:string) => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
    email_validation:(v:string) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
  };
  select=null;
  items:any[]=['Item1',
    'Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6'];

  checkbox:boolean=false;

  validate() {
    (<any>this.$refs.validattion).validate();
  }
  reset() {
    (<any>this.$refs.validattion).reset();
  }
  resetValidation() {
    (<any>this.$refs.validattion).resetValidation();
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Couple of things: 1. Could you please include the error you're encountering in this question? 2. I recommend https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#Ref for handling $refs.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. I really appreciate your comments. and I'll check my problem again and send it to you.